# How to confirm processes on AWS Cloud9

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud9, aws-cloud9

I forgot how to confirm processes on Cloud 9. How can I confirm processes on Cloud 9?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools bar like this `Tools -> Process List`